# Can not access com.google.auth.Credentials

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, firebase-admin

I am using the firebase admin SDK with IntelliJ whenever I try to run this code I got this error message:

> Error:(15, 50) java: cannot access com.google.auth.Credentials
>     class file for com.google.auth.Credentials not found

this is the code:

```
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class main {
    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream serviceAccount =
                new FileInputStream("C:/Users/fusion/Desktop/projects/aesf/google-services.json");

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                .setDatabaseUrl("https://myDataBaseName.firebaseio.com")
                .build();

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

    }
}
```

And this is the **gradle** file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
apply plugin: 'java'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:0.12.0'

}
```

gradle :

```
rootProject.name = 'aesf'
```

Answer (score -2):

Check you are using one of these

remove them

```
google-oauth-client-1.22.0.jar
google-oauth-client-appengine-1.22.0.jar
google-oauth-client-servlet-1.22.0.jar
```

also update your classpath
`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'`

Comment: where can i added /find them

Comment: in dependencies {}

Comment: like this??implementation'google-oauth-client-appengine-1.22.0.jar'

Comment: if not can you clarify how

Comment: can you show the code of project level and app level gradle file

Comment: I added both of them

Comment: If you have such in your app find it and remove them

Comment: Update the class path as well classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'